# TCP traffic redirection

Tags: tcp, port-forwarding, redirection

I am using an open source program called revinetd:

[revinetd.sourceforge.net](http://revinetd.sourceforge.net)

On server side, revinet listens for incoming connections on a defined port to act as a relay server.

Now, The server must open multiple ports in order to listen to connections from multiple machines.

Is there a method to open one single port on the server and then redirect every connection to other local ports ?

Thanks

Comment: Normally you don't nee to open multiple ports for multiple clients, you need to open multiple ports for multiple applications you want to redirect. Why don't get your applications directly listening to public?

Comment: I meant that every client needs to connect to port (that it is not used in the server), for that, I have to open many instances of revinetd server that listen to those ports..